# Changing Unique ID to Email Android Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Whenever i change it to `user.getEmail()` instead of `user.getUid()` , the application crashes. Anyone knows the reason behind it?

```
private void saveUserInformation() {
    String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
    String team = editTextTeam.getText().toString().trim();
    String pos = editTextPos.getText().toString().trim();

    UserInformation userInformation = new UserInformation(name, team, pos);

    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(userInformation);


    Toast.makeText(this, "Information saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Below is my Firebase Database Structure.

```
`{ "K05L8cmiqdg3jZapHbhpz219hpG3" : {

},"RmJ1ZfgxmqQ4bENGWCr8Y1dIwO12" : {

} "pHX5yYjzPYTZB0ek3ijeoH7rafD3" : {
}}
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events

Comment: I've tried ways such as: "Firebase rootRef = new Firebase("https://ltas-a6cf1.firebaseio.com/0Zs7aiWplRRJ5IJ5pazuUOxIdqz2/2016/10/27/AM
"
");" However it states that "Cannot resolve symbol 'Firebase'." Is this the correct way of doing so?

Comment: Your code is for the legacy Firebase, where I suspect you're using a newer SDK. Read the documentation that I linked, which contains complete instructions on how to [set up the SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and then [access the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/).

Comment: Managed to resolve that. Right now I am able to retrieve the value of AM from that specific unique ID that I am logged in with. What functions should I use so that when the user click on the name that is registered under a unique ID, he/she is able to retrieve the value of AM from there?

Comment: Instead of describing your problem, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40231561/edit) your question to include the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for spotting my mistakes as I am totally new to this whole thing. I edited my question with the current problem I am facing with right now.

Comment: Please include the error that you get in your question please. And if you include the stack trace (highly recommended) please point out how line numbers on the stack trace correspond to the code you posted.